# Not able to call external api's from google dialogflow web hook?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I tried calling an external api from inline editor of google dialogue flow. But not working. i am using the inline editor. Error i can see in the log is 'Error: Cannot find module 'request-promise-native'. Is there anywhere else i need to add this reference? package.JSON? if so how?

```
function AccountNumberHandler(agent) {
    const AccountNumber = agent.parameters.AccountNumber;

    if (AccountNumber) {
      //console.log(AccountNumber);
      const request = require('request-promise-native');
      agent.add('Unable to get result');
      const url = "xxxx";
      const data = "";
     return request.post(url, data)
          .then(jsonBody => {
              var body = JSON.parse(jsonBody);
              agent.add(body);
              return Promise.resolve(agent);
          })
          .catch(err => {
              console.error('Problem making network call', err);
              agent.add('Unable to get result');
              return Promise.resolve(agent);
          });      

        //agent.add(`Wow! I didn't know you knew ${AccountNumber}`);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome! Please [edit] your question and try to describe your problem more clearly. What is not working? Do you get an error message?

Comment: As @ventiseis said - the more information you provide, the better chance we have of helping you. Please update your question. What platform are you running your fulfillment in - your own environment or the built-in code editor? What error do you get? What does or doesn't happen? See [Hey Google, I Need Help With My Action](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/hey-google-i-need-help-with-my-action-8cf09714a20d)

Comment: i am using the inline editor. Error i can see in the log is 'Error: Cannot find module 'request-promise-native'. Is there anywhere else i need to add this reference? package.JSON? if so how?

Answer (score 1):

What @Prisoner answered above is correct, however, you may still see some problems while making calls to external APIs using inline editor. That's because inline editor uses firebase which blocks calls to external APIs in their free plan.

So you need to upgrade to their blaze plan which allows calls to external APIs. However, you will need to enter your card details so just keep this in mind.

I have created a video tutorial on how to connect your dialogflow agent to external APIs. Please have a look at this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4IPOeFCDxI

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You. That helps
Thank You so much. I was able to make an API call but log shows below error.
 Problem making network call { StatusCodeError: 500 - "{\"Message\":\"An error has occurred.\"}"
I am able to call the same API from POSTMAN without any issues.

Comment: Seems you are not passing the right data in the body of the post request. Make sure your data is a valid JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to add it to your package.json file.

To do this using the Dialogflow inline editor, you'll see two filenames at the top of the editor: index.js and package.json. Just click on the "package.json" one and edit it to add what you need to the "dependencies" section.

[image]

Comment: Thank You so much. I was able to make an API call but log shows below error.
 Problem making network call { StatusCodeError: 500 - "{\"Message\":\"An error has occurred.\"}"
I am able to call the same API from POSTMAN without any issues.

Comment: It sounds like you're having a problem with the code itself, or the API you're hitting has an issue with what you're sending. I suggest opening a new question with this problem, showing the code again, and any error or other debugging available.